# VBA Chart title does not populate

Tags: vba, excel, excel-charts

I have a list of data and I need to generate a chart for every two lines and give a chart title associated to the 1st line. Example of the data is:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBjxN.jpg)

And so on.

The code I am using to create the charts is:

```
Sub loopChart()

Dim mychart As Chart
Dim myRange As Range
Dim c As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim s As Integer
Dim ttl As String




r = 2
While r <= 10 '1=dataSource1, 4=dataSource2, 7=dataSource3
'set data source for the next chart

With Worksheets("Sheet9")
    Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(r, 2), .Cells(r + 1, 14))

End With
'create chart
Sheets("Chart").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select

    With ActiveChart
         ttl = Range("A" & r)
        .ChartType = xlLineMarkers 'xlLine
        .SetSourceData Source:=myRange, PlotBy:=xlRows  'sets source data for graph including labels
        .SetElement (msoElementLegendRight) 'including legend
        .HasTitle = True
        'dimentions & location:
        .Parent.Top = 244  'defines the coordinates of the top of the chart
        '.Parent.Left = r * 150  'defines the coordinates for the left side of the chart
        .Parent.Height = 200
        .Parent.Width = 300
        .ChartTitle.Formula = ttl
    End With

r = r + 2
Wend

End Sub
```

So, the 1st chart that generates should get the title on row 2, next chart should have title of row 4...
I always get the Chart title on 1st chart that generates but not on any of the other charts. Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Please fix below.

```
ttl = Range("A" & r)
```

to

```
ttl = Worksheets("Sheet9").Range("A" & r).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @Dy.Lee answer will do the trick but to go a bit further :

Try avoiding using `.select`

Proposed workaround :

```
Sub loopChart()

Dim Ch As Chart
Dim Sh1 As Worksheet: Set Sh1 = Sheets("Sheet9")
Dim Sh2 As Worksheet: Set Sh2 = Sheets("Chart")
Dim L As Integer

L = 0

For i = 2 To 18 Step 2
    Set Ch = Sh2.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    Ch.SetSourceData Sh1.Range(Sh1.Cells(i, 2), Sh1.Cells(i + 1, 14))
    Ch.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    Ch.SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)
    Ch.HasTitle = True
    Ch.Parent.Top = 244
    Ch.Parent.Height = 200
    Ch.Parent.Width = 300
    Ch.Parent.Left = L
    Ch.ChartTitle.Caption = Sh1.Cells(i, 1).Value
    L = L + 300
Next i

End Sub
```

Your code will create each graph at the same location so you'll see only one (the last one) hence the `Ch.Parent.Left` line with variable value.